# Is creating a "master-class" considered using a singleton or something else?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I want to know if code, containing a "master-class"(A class that should have only one instance) is considered implementing the "Singleton" design pattern or if there is another design pattern that follows this concept.

I created a class "GUI" and a class "MasterControl"
The class "MasterControl" defines alot of methods that interact with the GUI and contains a single "GUI" Instance on which it operates.

Code to demonstrate the basic idea.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    MasterControl controller = new MasterControl();
}

public class MasterControl{
    private GUI Servant;

    public MasterControl(){
        Servant = new GUI(this);
    }
}

public MasterControl(){
    Servant = new GUI(this);
}

public class GUI{
    GUIComponent c;
    MasterControl master;

    public GUI(MasterControl master){
        this.master = master;
        c = new GUIComponent(master);
    }
}
//And so on
```

Comment: singletons define by design to only allow 1 instance, where as instantiating a class only once will not really count as a singleton

Comment: Okay, but are there any design patterns that correspond with this concept of having one master-class instance that is passed on to other classes via constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Singleton design pattern means that it is impossible to create more than one instance of that class. Code that contains a "master class" is usually a class that represents the starting point of the code, it is proper format to initialize it once, but there is technically nothing stopping us from creating another instance of it. The presence of a master class does not necessarily make it a Singleton design pattern.

The classic implementation of a Singleton design pattern involves a private constructor with its own 'getter' method, as well as a static & uninitialized instance variable which will represent the single instance of the Singleton class. This design makes the constructor only available through the getter method, and can therefore be programmed to only be called when the getter method is called the first time. This would initialize the instance variable, which would then be returned from here on out. It would look something like this:

```
class Singleton {
    private static Singleton instance;
    private Singleton() {}

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new Singleton();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: this implementation is not thread safe. You may want to use the *static holder pattern* when implementig singletons